# Como controlar as migrações dois contextos distintos?

Tags: c#, migrations, entity-framework-core

Tenho dois contextos e gostaria de saber como faço para ativar cada um deles.

Por exemplo

```
Add-Migration Contexto 1, 
Add-Migration 2
```

Como posso fazer para adicionar novas *migrations* para cada contexto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deverá adicionar o parâmetro `-Context` no comando `Add-Migrations`

```
Add-Migration Teste -Context:DoisContext.Data.OutroContext
```

No exemplo que montei os meus Context estão da seguinte forma

```
public class OutroContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Teste> Testes { get; set; }

    public OutroContext(DbContextOptions<OutroContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Detalhe importante para seus construtores, onde ambos estão recebendo o `DbContextOptions`.

Tive que adicionar também no `ConfigureServices` da classe `Startup`.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddDbContext<OutroContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```